# Provider for Microsoft Excel version 2.0

Tags: c#, excel

In FoxPro there is a command like this:

"Copy to [path] [condition] xls" that export data from FoxPro DBFs to Microsoft Excel.In this case excel version is 2.0.

Problem:I want to read this exported excel file with C#.So i try to use this providers:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

With this properties:

```
Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;
```

or

```
Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;
```

But they didn't work(I caught this error):

```
External table is not in the expected format.
```

Is there any way to read Microsoft Excel 2.0 files in C#?I need a provider to read it for example as a DataTable and I don't read it by using the VSTO!

PS: This Exported file are shown correctly by Microsoft Excel 97 (and later)easily.I don't know why I can't read they with C# and Microsoft Excel Providers for C#?

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2.0 is a rather old file format but you should be able to use a generic ODBC connection string like this:

```
DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=16;DBQ=C:\MyExcelFile.xls;

// then use a query like
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Should this not work you might have more success with a managed library like [Excel Data Reader found on CodePlex](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

Perhaps post a copy of the code and a screen shot of the Excel file as it can sometimes be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: +1, although "rather old" is an understatement. I think it was from around the time Gates made the infamous "640K is more than enough" statement. ;-)

Comment: Thanks dude,It was really great(Excel Data Reader).But it just can read Excel 97 and later.unfortunately it can't read Excel 2.0 files.It Show a inner exception like this:"Error: Invalid file signature."

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change your Foxpro code to:

```
COPY TO [yourpath\yourfile.csv] TYPE DELIMITED
```

or

```
COPY TO [yourpath\yourfile.xls] TYPE XL5
```

You should be able to read from these file types.

Comment: Thank you,We have many program that generate many report to Excel with simple "Copy to"command,We can't change all of them.So I need some algorithm to read these Excel files in C#.